# How to fetch values from database only for particular columns in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

In the below screenshot , I want to fetch values for column 2 and column 4 values to be fetched from database. The column 1 and Column 3 has to be hardcoded. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decalre two array and this array should be hardcoded. and match with